# Can I hide certain keyframes that belong to the same object?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm animating an animal and want to hide the all the keyframes to focus on just one leg. Is it possible to hide certain keyframes even when they belong to the same object?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's what you're looking for

[image]